# Best performing way to constantly updating data in Elastic index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexes in Elastic with daily generated data about products (>10.000.000), but I need to update this data constantly during the day too. Things I need to update are for example prices, availability or sorting properties of a product.

I was wondering what would be the best way to handle this scenario?

1. I can send the changed properties to the index, but I've read that it is a costly task so when it happens constantly it drops performance on the searches.
2. In a relation DB we would only update a specific table containing that data... but that doesn't exist in ES.
3. We could split the index in seperate indexes so not all changes are done on one index, this could be better for performance. But the search would become more difficult I guess, when we filter on one index and need to combine it with results from another index. I think instead of only fetching 15 results from the single index in this case we always need to fetch larger results to be able to get the best combination of both indexes?

Any other thoughts, best practises or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you update a single field, elasticsearch has to reindex the entire record, which indeed can cause a significant indexing load. However, with only 10 million updates per day, so you might be able to get away with simply updating an entire record. I would suggest testing it first before jumping to more complex solutions.

In case your records are huge and your server cannot keep up with updates, you might want to try split the records into two parts - a static part and a dynamic part. You will then index these two parts as different records with the static part playing the role of the parent and dynamic part playing the role of a child in the [join field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/parent-join.html). Such setup will have a negative effect on the search performance, but it should speed up the indexing performance.